# read the value of a child UISelectItems component in a parent custm component

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component, selectonemenu

I have developed a JSF custom component, based on UISelectOne component and I want implement a  custom renderer for it. To specify the list of items I use a child UISelectItems component (through f:selectItems tag) to indicate a list of plain Java objects (not SelectItem objects).
However, when I want to implement Renderer.encodeEnd and get the value of the child UISelectItems component, instead of getting a list of SelectItems (as indicated in the documentation) I get my original list of plain Java objects.

I imagined that internally, UISelectItems will still be working with SelectItem object, however the custom tag will provide a mean to convert the list of Java objects into a list of SelectItem and I will only see, internally, SelectItem objects. Which is not the case.

Of course, I can just consider my own plain Java objects and proceed with the implementation of the encodeEn method. But I want the component to fully benefit from the fact that through f:selectItems you can specify any list of Java objects as long as you mention also itemValue and itemLabel attributes.

Thanks.